# Unable to generate dataset to World Map on pygal.maps.world module

Tags: python, csv, dataset, maps

I am trying to use a csv ([wb_hiv_prevalence_csv_file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aczqekxkgjLZBxVZSnKGOxcn-1n54qT8)) to plot HIV prevalence on a pygal map for data visualization purposes. The other aspects of the code are working when I print the relevant data (e.g. `hiv_d_2018`, `country_name`, etc). However after all the effort when I create the svg file the map is blank without the usual colored data visualizations. Kindly assist me know where I am getting it wrong. Thanks.

Code to process the data and create the map.

```
import csv
import pygal.maps.world
from country_codes import get_country_code
# Get the country names, country codes and HIV data from file.
filename = 'wb_hiv_prevalence.csv'
with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header_row = next(reader)

    country_names, hiv_data_2018 = [], []
    for row in reader:
        country_name = (row[0])
        hiv_d_2018 = (row[62])

        country_names.append(country_name)
        hiv_data_2018.append(hiv_d_2018)

        #print(country_name)
        #print(hiv_data_2018)   

        code = get_country_code(country_name)
        if code and hiv_d_2018 != '':
            cc_hiv = code + ': ' + str(hiv_d_2018) + ':  ' + country_name
            #print(cc_hiv)

        elif code and hiv_d_2018 == '':
            cc_zero_hiv = code + ': Zero Hiv Prevalence- ' + country_name
            #print(cc_zero_hiv)

        else:
            error = 'ERROR - ' + country_name
            #print(error)
        #print(hiv_d_2018)                  
wm = pygal.maps.world.World()
wm.title = 'World HIV prevalence rates in 2018, by Country'
wm.add('HIV prevalence rate 0-24%', hiv_d_2018)
wm.render_to_file('wb_hiv_prevalence.svg')
```

Code to get the country codes from pygal module.

```
from pygal.maps.world import COUNTRIES
from pygal_maps_world import i18n

def get_country_code(country_name):
    """Return the Pygal 2-digit country code for the given country."""
    for code, name in COUNTRIES.items():
        if name == country_name:
            return code 

    # If the country was not found, return None.
    return None
```

[image: World HIV prevalence rates in 2018, by Country]

Comment: You're welcome. I wish I could help answering this, but I never used `pygal`.

Comment: Also, where did you get the `wb_hiv_prevalence` csv? this would make easier for people to run your code.

Comment: I got the file from the World bank's website. I have shared the hyperlink of the file from my GoogleDrive file. I believe it can be assessed now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make dictionary and pass it to **wm.add** function. Since there is some data without values in CSV file or '',standard float conversion will throw an error.You exclude those values in if condition, and there convert strings to floats(hiv_d_2018)

```
import csv
import pygal.maps.world
from country_codes import get_country_code
# Get the country names, country codes and HIV data from file.
filename = 'wb_hiv_prevalence.csv'
with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header_row = next(reader)

    new_dict1={}

    country_names, hiv_data_2018 = [], []
    for row in reader:
        country_name = (row[0])
        code = get_country_code(country_name)
        hiv_d_2018 = (row[62])

        country_names.append(country_name)
        hiv_data_2018.append(hiv_d_2018)

        
        if code and hiv_d_2018 != '':
            new_dict[code]=float(hiv_d_2018)

        
        else:
            error = 'ERROR - ' + country_name
            #print(error)
        #print(hiv_d_2018)                  
wm = pygal.maps.world.World()
wm.title = 'World HIV prevalence rates in 2018, by Country'
wm.add('HIV prevalence rate 0-24%', new_dict)
wm.render_to_file('wb_hiv_prevalence.svg')
```